# How to add trigger key to my javascript project

Tags: javascript, html, triggers, keyboard, enter

How can I add trigger key to my button when I add something to input area?

My code:

```js
let animals = [];

function add() {
  let addAnimal = document.getElementById("enter").value;
  animals.push(addAnimal);
  let openList = "<ul>";
  let text = "";
  let closeList = "</ul>"
  
  for (i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + animals[i] + "</li>";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = openList + text + closeList;
}
```

```html
<input id="enter" />
<button onclick="add()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Wrap your HTML in a <form>, handle the form's `submit` event and call `.preventDefault()` on it: https://jsfiddle.net/2bo38nvL/

Comment: This should work as expected if you have an element with `demo` as id. Something like  `<div id="demo" />`

Comment: @adiga I believe OP wants to be able to press enter to submit the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add event listener on keyboard's events you can use the `keydown` event and then filter the events based on the [keyCodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

Here an example working when pressing enter:

```js
let animals = [];

function add() {
  let addAnimal = document.getElementById("enter").value;
  animals.push(addAnimal);
  let openList = "<ul>";
  let text = "";
  let closeList = "</ul>"
  
  for (i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + animals[i] + "</li>";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = openList + text + closeList;
}

function keyCallback(event) {
  if(event.key === "Enter") {
    add();
  }
}

addEventListener("keydown", keyCallback);
```

```html
<input id="enter" />
<button onclick="add()">Submit</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```